# two dimensional array highcharts Active Record Associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, highcharts

I am trying to make a two dimensional array for use in a high charts pie chart. I'm using the gem lazy_high_charts to create the charts. I didn't include the actual chart code, because that is working with dummy data, I just need to figure out how to dynamically make the same array that I hard coded.

I've looked all over the place and I've been working on this a couple days and nothing seems to work. Please help!

I am trying to get it to look like this:

```
[['Google Organic', 1],['Facebook', 1],['Radio', 2],['Pens', 1], ['Other', 2]]
```

Where Google Organic, etc. are based off the foreign key in a Leads database column in a has_many belongs_to association. The numbers are the count of how many times each id appears for each user.

Right now I got it to this, this is correct, but I'm not sure how to turn the id into the actual name:

```
[[3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 2], [7, 1], [8, 2]]
```

It is going through the nonleadaction_id column in the Leads db table and counting each time each one of the id's shows up. I then need to get the association there so I know that "Google Organic" showed up once.

So ideally I'd want to change the 3 into: "Google Organic", the 4 into "Facebook", etc.

Lead Model

```
belongs_to :user
has_one :nonleadaction
```

User Model

```
has_many :leads
```

NonLeadAction Model

```
belongs_to :lead
```

Leads_Controller:

```
  def show
    @user = current_user
    @actions_breakdown = @user.leads.group(:nonleadaction_id).distinct.count.to_a.drop(1)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved this:

```
def leads_breakdown
    e = self.opportunities.group(:category_id).distinct.count.to_a.drop(1).flatten
    evalues = e.values_at(* e.each_index.select {|i| i.even?})
    Category.find(evalues).map { |c| [c.reason, c.id]  }
end

def source_breakdown
    e = self.opportunities.group(:source).distinct.count.to_a
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function.

```
def steve(array)

      # slice array to get index 0 of each sub array
      sliceArray = array[0..2].map { |row| row[0] }

      # create a hash with appropriate values
      strHash = { 1 => "google", 2 => "facebook", 3 => "reddit" }; 

      # map the values to your sliced array
      webMap = sliceArray.map { |e| strHash[e] }

      # slice array again for index 1 of each sub array
      sliceIndexOne = array[0..2].map { |row| row[1] }

      #merge two new arrays
      mergedArray = webMap.zip(sliceIndexOne)

      # return array  
      return mergedArray  

end
```